# How to add a title or individual coloring to a terminal window?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am working now on some really exiting project and I am using about six terminals at the same time. Normally I use Ubuntu's default terminal which is currently the GNOME Terminal 3.20.2

Sometimes I get confused between my opened terminals, because their content is looking so similar.

**So I ask is there a way to add a title or some coloring to the Terminal window?**

Comment: You're using Ubuntu 17.04, right?

Comment: Yes, right now I'm using 17.04. But I'll upgrade to 17.10, soon.

Comment: Thanks to @muru for the duplicates. Well  https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title uses `gnome-terminal --title="SOME TITLE HERE"`. But the `--title` option seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/q/616404/507051 helps?

Comment: `echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"` to change the title in a running terminal window, or with `wmctrl` for the currently active window: `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "MyWindowTitle"`.

Comment: @eDeviser the `echo`+control code method should still work

Comment: Sorry, the echo command and the title command above do not work for me. The window's title stays the same.