# How to make the top bar of my terminal say what command is running?

Tags: command-line

I often run commands in parallel that take a long time to finish and sometimes I lose track of what is running where since they output basically the same sort of information on screen.

Do you know of any way to find out what command is running in what terminal?

Comment: Not sure if this still works, but this might help too besides @dessert s excellent answer. → https://askubuntu.com/questions/774532/how-to-change-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-04/774543#774543

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from [Bash - Update terminal title by running a second command · U&L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7110386/6164712) and slightly changed:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$(history 1 | sed "s/^[0-9 ]* \+//")\007"' DEBUG
```

This (ab)uses the `DEBUG` signal as a trigger to update the title with the last entry from your history, i.e. the last command you executed, via an [XTerm Control Sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html). Add the line to your `~/.bashrc` to have the feature enabled in every new terminal window.

To print other command output alongside in the title, say the current directory with `pwd` followed by ": " and the currently running command,  I recommend using `printf` as follows:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$(printf "%s: %s" "$(pwd)" "$(history 1 | sed "s/^[0-9 ]* \+//")")\007"' DEBUG
```

---

Some terminal emulators allow you to specify a dynamic title and even give you the command name as an option so that you don't even need to fiddle around – I searched and found it in `yakuake`'s profile settings.

Answer (score 2):

The terminal window title could be changed by changing of the value of the variable [`$PS1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Variables) - the primary prompt string. <sup>[[1]](https://askubuntu.com/a/702773/566421) [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/a/774543/566421)</sup>. We could combine this solution with the idea of using the `history` command from the [Dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/983075/566421).

---

**Approach 1: Update the value of `$PS1` automatically.** (Update)

Add the following lines to the bottom of the file `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# Change the terminal window title, based on the last executed command
rtitle() {
        # If the variable $PS1_bak is unset,
        # then store the original value of $PS1 in $PS1_bak and chang $PS1
        # else restore the value of $PS1 and unset @PS1_bak
        if [ -z "${PS1_bak}" ]; then
                PS1_bak=$PS1
                PS1+='\e]2;$(history 1 | sed "s/^[0-9 ]* \+//")\a'
        else
                PS1=$PS1_bak
                unset PS1_bak
        fi
};
export -f rtitle        # Export the function to be accessible in sub shells
#rtitle                 # Uncomment this line to change the default behaviour
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal and use the function in this way:

- Execute `rtitle` to start changing the terminal window title automatically, based on the last executed command.
- Execute `rtitle` once again to return to the default behaviour.

---

**Approach 2: Update the value of `$PS1` manually.** (Initial answer)

Add the following lines to the bottom of the file `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
set-title() {                                                                                 # Set a title of the current terminal window
        [[ -z ${@} ]] && TITLE="$(history 2 | head -1 | sed "s/^[0-9 ]* \+//")" || TITLE="$@" # If the title is not provided use the previous command
        [[ -z ${PS_ORIGINAL} ]] && PS_ORIGINAL="${PS1}" || PS_ORIGINAL="${PS_ORIGINAL}"       # Use the original value of PS1 for each future change
        PS1="${PS_ORIGINAL}"'\e]2;'"$TITLE"'\a'                                               # Change the prompt (the value of PS1)
}; export -f set-title
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal and use the function in this way:

- `set-title <something>` will change the terminal window title to `<something>`.
- `set-title` without argument will change the terminal window title to the previous command.

---

References and examples:

- [Ubuntu 15.04 fresh install: Can't rename gnome-terminal tabs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616404/ubuntu-15-04-fresh-install-cant-rename-gnome-terminal-tabs/702773#702773)
- [How to change Terminal Title in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774532/how-to-change-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-04/774543#774543)
- [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ4xd.gif); [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRZNp.gif)